# SQL Join 2 tables even if there is no matching data

Tags: mysql, sql

I am working to join the contents of my tables, I am trying to join two tables while still getting the results from table 'movies' even if there is no matching record in table 'users_ratings'. But it seems not working I get only one result.

--movies Table (100 records)

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `movies` (
  `ID` int(20) NOT NULL,
  `title_name` vachar(255) NOT NULL,
  `creation_date` datetime NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

--ratings Table (1 records)

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users_ratings` (
  `ID` int(20) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `type_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `type_name` vachar(255) NOT NULL,
  `score` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `creation_date` datetime NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

--My Query

```
SELECT name_table.*, ur.type_id, count(ur.type_id) vote_count
FROM `movies` name_table 
left JOIN users_ratings ur ON name_table.id = ur.type_id
WHERE ur.type_name= 'movies'
GROUP BY ur.type_id
Order BY vote_count DESC
```

--Query Results

```
ID    title_name  creation_date        type_id  vote_count
1     Avatar      2014-05-20 00:00:00  1        1
```

--Results I'm trying to get (Should I get 100 records)

```
ID    title_name      creation_date        type_id  vote_count
1     Avatar          2014-05-20 00:00:00  1        1
2     Avengers        2014-05-20 00:00:00  NULL     NULL
3     Ant-Man         2014-05-20 00:00:00  NULL     NULL
4     Jurassic World  2014-05-20 00:00:00  NULL     NULL
5     Rampage         2014-05-20 00:00:00  NULL     NULL
6     Black Panther   2014-05-20 00:00:00  NULL     NULL
7     Tombe Raider    2014-05-20 00:00:00  NULL     NULL
8     Deadpool        2014-05-20 00:00:00  NULL     NULL
9     Pacific Rim     2014-05-20 00:00:00  NULL     NULL
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to your `join` being wrong, I think the `group by` is too.

I think you want:

```
SELECT m.*, MAX(ur.type_id), COUNT(ur.type_id) as vote_count
FROM movies m LEFT JOIN
     users_ratings ur
     ON m.id = ur.type_id AND ur.type_name= 'movies'
GROUP BY m.id
ORDER BY vote_count DESC;
```

In general, using something like `SELECT m.*` in a `GROUP BY` query would be incorrect.  This is the one case where this is allowed, because `id` is unique in the `movies` table.

Note that `type_id` now has an aggregation function in the `SELECT`.

Answer (score 1):

Since, you have put an explicit Where condition of `ur.type_name = movies`, so it filters out the result after the Left join. You need to shift your Where condition to `LEFT JOIN ON` matching.

Try the following instead:

```
SELECT name_table.*, ur.type_id, count(ur.type_id) vote_count
FROM `movies` name_table 
left JOIN users_ratings ur ON name_table.id = ur.type_id 
                              AND ur.type_name= 'movies'
GROUP BY name_table.id 
Order BY vote_count DESC
```

**Note:** [As pointed out by @Strawberry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52457596/sql-join-2-tables-even-if-there-is-no-matching-data/52457608?noredirect=1#comment91857449_52457608), you should avoid using wildcard (*) based Select; and get only specific columns as required by your application code.

Additionally, you may read [Why is SELECT * considered harmful?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3639861/why-is-select-considered-harmful)

Comment: ...and only select the columns you actually want returned

Comment: @MappyLord check the edited answer. Your group by was also wrong

Answer (score 0):

Try it: `AND ( ur.type_name = 'movies' OR ur.type_name IS NULL)`.
The null results will be displayed.

```
SELECT name_table.*, ur.type_id, count(ur.type_id) vote_count
FROM `movies` name_table 
left JOIN users_ratings ur ON name_table.id = ur.type_id 
                    AND ( ur.type_name = 'movies' OR ur.type_name IS NULL)
GROUP BY name_table.id 
Order BY vote_count DESC;`
```